# Access variables from functions

Tags: javascript

I'm C# developer who is trying to use object oriented programing in javascripts. For the following code

```
var np =  np || {};

 np.Class1 = function () {

    var var1,
        var2,
        var3;

    var init = function(a) {
        var1 = a;
        this.var2 = a;
        init3(a);
    };

    var init3 = function(b) {
        this.var3 = b;
    };

    return {
        init: init,
        var1: var1,
        var2: var2,
        var3: var3
    };
};

var t = new np.Class1();
t.init("t");
console.log("var1 " + t.var1);
console.log("var2 " + t.var2);
console.log("var3 " + t.var3);
```

I'm getting:

```
 var1 undefined 
 var2 t 
 var3 undefined
```

The only way which I can get to private variables in `Class1` is to use `this.var2 = a;` but it is not working for function which is call from other function. How can I access to private variables from function `init3()`?

Edited

Even if I change function `init3()` like this

```
var init3 = function(b) {
  var3 = b;
};
```

the result is the same. So question is still valid. How can I manipulate private variables from function?

Comment: Use `var3 = b;`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: `a`? `b`? You didn't define them.

Comment: `var3 = b;` is not working too...

Comment: `a` and `b` are parameters of function, set when calling the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your return statement

```
return {
        init: init,
        var1: var1,
        var2: var2,
        var3: var3
    };
```

is exposing (setting as properties of the returned object) the *initial* values of the variables (before `init` has run), which are `undefined`. You later overwrite the exposed value of `var2` by setting `this.var2 = a`, and try to do something similar for `var3`, but (as noted in previous answers) it doesn't work because `this` within `init3` refers to `window`. So the object properties `var1` and `var3` remain undefined and only `var2` changes.

If these variables were objects (including arrays and functions, as `init` is), they would be passed by reference rather than by value, so the output of `console.log("var1 " + t.var1);` etc. would represent the current value, not the initial value.

For illustration, [try this](http://jsfiddle.net/kBv9g/):

```
np.Class1 = function () {
    var someVariables = {},
        self;

    var init = function(a) {
        self = this; // self now refers to the object from which init was called
        someVariables.var1 = a;
        this.var2 = a;
        init3(a);
    };

    var init3 = function(b) {
        self.var3 = b;
    };

    return {
        init: init,
        vars: someVariables
    };
};

var t = new np.Class1();
t.init("t");
console.log("var1 " + t.vars.var1); // 't'
console.log("var2 " + t.var2); // 't'
console.log("var3 " + t.var3); // 't'
var newObj = {init: t.init}
newObj.init(true);
console.log(newObj); // Object {init: function, var2: true, var3: true}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're exposing the local `var3` in your returned object, but you never set it to anything; you only ever set `this.var3`. You'd have to set `var3 = b` for it to return a value.

Additionally, if your intention is for them to be private, why are you exposing them directly?  Wouldn't you rather expose functions that manipulate the private state of your object ([since you're trying to be object-oriented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29))?

Comment: I'm exposing them just to validate it, just for test purpose. I know this whole class is quite strange but my question is about accesing private variables from functions.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using:

```
init3(a);
```

Try:

```
init3.call(this, a);
```

Why? When you use `init3(a)`, `this` is set to the global object (`window` in browser environments). The `call` method of functions lets you set `this` to something else. In this case, we just want to propagate our `this` value.